# Minumun cart amount except for several specific products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I'm using the following code "[Minimum cart amount except for a specific product in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51514710/11987538)" in my php that allows the override of the Woocommerce minimum cart value of $130.

Works fine but only for one defined product. In this case `product_id 2649`

I am trying to further modify this code by adding lines of `except_product_id...` 
but that does not help.

How can I modify to make a list of exceptions by `product id`?

Any help appreciated

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'min_cart_amount' );
function min_cart_amount() {
    ## ----- EXCLUDES A PRODUCT FROM MINIMUM ORDER DOLLAR VALUE Your Settings below ----- ##

    $min_cart_amount   = 130; // Minimum cart amount
    $except_product_id = 2649; // Except for this product ID
    $except_product_id = 2659; // Except for this product ID
    $except_product_id = 1747; // Except for this product ID



    // Loop though cart items searching for the defined product
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_id() == $except_product_id || $cart_item['product_id'] == $except_product_id )
            return; // Exit if the defined product is in cart
    }

    if( WC()->cart->subtotal < $min_cart_amount ) {
        wc_add_notice( sprintf(
            __( "<strong>A Minimum of %s is required before checking out.</strong><br>The current cart's total is %s" ),
            wc_price( $min_cart_amount ),
            wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
        ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite your variable by using the same naming convention on every new line. So if you want to apply this for multiple IDs you have to put them in an array.

```php
function min_cart_amount() {
    ## ----- EXCLUDES A PRODUCT FROM MINIMUM ORDER DOLLAR VALUE Your Settings below ----- ##

    $min_cart_amount   = 130; // Minimum cart amount
    $except_product_id = array ( 2649, 2659, 1747 ); // Except for this product ID

    // Loop though cart items searching for the defined product
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Exit if the defined product is in cart
        if ( in_array( $product_id, $except_product_id) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    if( WC()->cart->subtotal < $min_cart_amount ) {
        wc_add_notice( sprintf(
            __( "<strong>A Minimum of %s is required before checking out.</strong><br>The current cart's total is %s" ),
            wc_price( $min_cart_amount ),
            wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
        ), 'error' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'min_cart_amount', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much - easy enough when you get the right syntax. Really appreciate your input and help.